# How to connect two provider hosted apps in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

How to connect two provider hosted apps ?.How the communication happens between two provider hosted apps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't. SharePoint apps are not designed to be able to "talk together".

Apps can share the same data source however. So you can update data in one app and the changes will appear in the second app.

It's the same logic for AppParts. They cannot connect, but they can share the same data source.

Comment: Using PostMessage() can we connect two appparts. beacuse we are deploying provider hosted apps as app parts.